# PyTorch: Different training accuracies using same random seed

Tags: python, validation, pytorch, random-seed

I am trying to evaluate my model on the whole training set after each epoch.
This is what I did:

```
torch.manual_seed(1)
model = ConvNet(num_classes=num_classes)
cost_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)  

def compute_accuracy(model, data_loader):
    correct_pred, num_examples = 0, 0
    for features, targets in data_loader:
        logits = model(features)
        predicted_labels = torch.argmax(logits, 1)
        num_examples += targets.size(0)
        correct_pred += (predicted_labels == targets).sum()
    return correct_pred.float()/num_examples * 100

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model = model.train()
    for features, targets in train_loader:
        logits = model(features)
        cost = cost_fn(logits, targets)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        cost.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    model = model.eval()
    print('Epoch: %03d/%03d training accuracy: %.2f%%' % (
          epoch+1, num_epochs, 
          compute_accuracy(model, train_loader)))
```

the output was convincing:

```
Epoch: 001/005 training accuracy: 89.08%
Epoch: 002/005 training accuracy: 90.41%
Epoch: 003/005 training accuracy: 91.70%
Epoch: 004/005 training accuracy: 92.31%
Epoch: 005/005 training accuracy: 92.95%
```

But then I added another line at the end of the training loop, to also evaluate the model on the whole test set after each epoch:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model = model.train()
    for features, targets in train_loader:
        logits = model(features)
        cost = cost_fn(logits, targets)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        cost.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    model = model.eval()
    print('Epoch: %03d/%03d training accuracy: %.2f%%' % (
          epoch+1, num_epochs, 
          compute_accuracy(model, train_loader)))
    print('\t\t testing accuracy: %.2f%%' % (compute_accuracy(model, test_loader)))
```

But the training accuracies started to change:

```
Epoch: 001/005 training accuracy: 89.08%
         testing accuracy: 87.66%
Epoch: 002/005 training accuracy: 90.42%
         testing accuracy: 89.04%
Epoch: 003/005 training accuracy: 91.84%
         testing accuracy: 90.01%
Epoch: 004/005 training accuracy: 91.86%
         testing accuracy: 89.83%
Epoch: 005/005 training accuracy: 92.45%
         testing accuracy: 90.32%
```

Am I doing something wrong? I expected the training accuracies to remain the same because the manual seed is 1 in both cases.
Is this an expected output ?

Comment: If model.eval() is doing random-related stuff, it will affect all the random numbers that come after it.

Imagine random as being some infinite stream of random bits that is determined at the time of manual_seed. All calls to generate a random number use the same stream.

I think seeding before each call to "train()" will give you the consistent results you want

Comment: I thought I was doing something wrong in my implementation. But looks like it has to do with the behavior of random numbers. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The `random seed` had been set wasn't stop the model for learning to get higher accuracy becuase the `random seed` is a number for Pseudo random. In this case, you had told the model to shuffle the training data with a random number("1").